# Changing a formula's reference based on a cell value

Tags: excel, formula, vba

I'm not sure if it is possible as I've been looking around the web for a while now, but I'm trying to change the worksheet a formula is referencing based on a cells value.

I created a dropdown list with all of the worksheets names (ex. Report, May 2018, ect.), and the formula in question is:

> =COUNTA(Report!A:A)-1
>
> =COUNTIF(Report!J:J, ">0")

EDIT:  I have gotten a solution for the first formula, but I have been unable to get the second one to work as it keeps getting hung up on the COUNTIFs criteria ">0". Here is what I was trying to use:

> =COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&G2&"'!J:J), ">0")

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

With the drop-down in a1 try INDIRECT¹,

```
=COUNTA(indirect("'"&a1&"'!A:A"))-1

=COUNTIF(indirect("'"&a1&"'!J:J), "FREIGHT")+COUNTIF(indirect("'"&a1&"'!J:J), "CREDIT")
```

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: Maybe add a cautionary: `indirect` causes a recalculation whenever **anything** changes, yes? That could cause quite a delay if the worksheets are large enough.

Comment: tbh, I usually avoid indirect but that cannot be avoided in this case without vba. Caution added.

Comment: Awesome!  This worked perfectly as this is just a calculation worksheet.I did try to use this in a couple of other formulas as well, but received an error when it came to the criteria.  I'm updating my question to reflect this.

Comment: It shouldn't. indirect can be used anywhere a reference is used except a closed workbook. You likely just have a minor syntax issue.

Comment: >=COUNTIF(Report!J:J, "FREIGHT")+COUNTIF(Report!J:J,"CREDIT")   When I tried to insert the indirect function it keeps getting hung up on "FREIGHT", so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: See edit above.